# php: trying to find temporary copy of the uploaded files on the server

Tags: php

```
if ($_FILES['doc']['error'][$i] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['doc']['name'][$i]);

                        $filename = md5($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'].'.'.$tmp[0].'.'.time()).'.'.$tmp[sizeof($tmp) - 1];
                        var_dump($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'][$i]);
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'][$i], PATH_site.$this->uploadDir.$filename)) {
```

In above script, I used `var_dump($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'][$i]);` to output the the temporary copy of the file, in front end, it shows:

```
string(14) "/tmp/phpFs1iE7" string(14) "/tmp/phpGAgJFX"
```

Then I went to `/home/thejob/tmp`, but did not see such files: `phpFs1iE7`, `phpGAgJFX`, I used ssh and enabled `show hidden files`. so I just wonder why I can not see these temporary copy of the files on the server?

Comment: Because they are not in your home directory. PHP clearly states where your files are. They are in `/tmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are *temporary*. They are so temporary, PHP deletes them at the end of the request. They're literally only there while the PHP script is running, and since it probably finishes within a second, you'll have a hard time seeing those files in the short time they're there.

As pointed out above, they're also in `/tmp`, not `/home/thejob/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system, a filename beginning with a slash indicates a path relative to the root directory, so `/tmp/phpFs1iE7` will be at exactly that location, not at `/home/thejob/tmp/phpFs1iE7`. Also, the temporary file may be deleted when the script finishes, so might need to put in a `sleep()` call to make the script pause while you look at the file (if you really need to do so). If you are trying to find out why your script isn't working, then `var_dump(PATH_site.$this->uploadDir.$filename)` might be a good place to look.